# Can a man have invasive medical procedures forced on him during a paternity dispute?

Tags: united-states, texas, parental-rights

If a woman has a man's child and does not acknowledge him as the father, can she later force the man to give blood as to prove him the father (If she for instance decides his money is good enough again). What if the man has Trypanophobia, will that change anything?

Comment: In what jurisdiction (state, country)?

Answer (score 5):

She can't force him, but the court can. This would be a court ordered paternity test. If one parent can't give blood for some reason they could do something else like a cheek swab.

Comment: Indeed, https://www.texasattorneygeneral.gov/child-support/paternity/court-ordered-paternity suggests that a cheek swab is the normal procedure nowadays.  They don't mention blood tests at all.